# SignalR client for Dart/Flutter Via Platform Channel

Tags: flutter, signalr, flutter-platform-channel

I am building flutter mobile app. which suppose to connect to .net framework SignalR server, as you know, there is not such client package available on pub.dev, the only packages available there requires .net core version which is not available in my server. (https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_client , https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_core).

Now, one suggested solution is using flutter platform channel which means i can implement the Signal R integration on native side for both android and iOS then send/receive the events via platform channels.

Another suggestion was building my own client which i tried but it was a nightmare due to the lack of technical references and the complexity of the signalR protocol.

My question here, is it risky to use platform channels for heavy events streaming such as socket connection? almost every screen in my app. depends on the socket connection, and according to my knowledge, the platform channels should be used only for light weight usage.

I appreciate any input regarding this or any suggestion.

Comment: If you need to add a lot of native code for every screen which is the point of using flutter?

Comment: To be honest, i didn't get your comment. if i decided to use platform channels, then i only need to implement the native Signalr integration inside android / iOS folder, then i build a platform channel to pass the messages between the native implementation and my flutter code. but my question was .. is it risky? should i expect a performance issues for example ???

Comment: what .net framework version you are using ?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.8